# I commit a single file from git , but multiple files get commited onto the server?

Tags: php, git, github

I AM USING VCS SOFTWARE FOR GIT. 
I added a file : "Somefile" and then committed onto the server.

But following files also gets commited : 
[The file names that gets added to git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBaz4.png)

I checked the files added , before committing and it shows only 1 file.
I have also unticked the checkbox for any other files.

Still how does these files gets added and 
how to solve this ?
It works fine when i do commit with git terminal.

These files exist in : /php/htdocs/inc/js/tiny_mce/plugins/ibrowser/scripts/phpthumb/cache

Comment: can you paste your .gitignore file here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a .gitignore  file and add

```
*.JPE
```

This will ignore any file ending in .JPE

Comment: I did that sir . It still gets commited

Answer (score 0):

I think, you no need to put cache files to your git remote repository.
So, the best solution to fix this issue - put cache files under git ignore.

1. Create `.gitignore` file in root directory if this file doesn't exist yet.
2. Add directory, which you want to ignore in `.gitignore` file:

   `/php/htdocs/inc/js/tiny_mce/plugins/ibrowser/scripts/phpthumb/cache/*.JPE`

   Good luck.

Comment: I did that sir . It still gets commited.

Comment: This files added to index (staging) area?

Comment: No, these files were not added to stagging

Comment: i did not commit them, neither added them  to stagging still they get commited. It only happens with this cache path

Comment: So, you have this files as Untracked?

Comment: If your files shown as Untracked, maybe you put incorrect path of the cache directory to your ```.gitignore``` file.

Comment: Sry i forgot to mention about the software (VCS). Please Refer my edited question. :)

Comment: It doesn't matter, which UI you are using for Git. If you added your path in ```.gitignore``` file correctly - your software will not show files.